# bash changing directory when started

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have both *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows* and *Cygwin bash* installed on my machine, and both are setup to have the same `~` folder (via `/mnt/c/source` and `/cygdrive/c/source` respectively).

When I start Ubuntu's bash prompt via `bash --login -i` (or just `bash --login`) from any directory, I get a prompt running from within that directory; however, when I start Cygwin's bash via the same command, the current directory is overridden, and the prompt is always at `~`. See the screenshots for a simple example.

My user directory's `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are of course the same, as both are using the same user directory. I've looked into Cygwin's `/etc/bash.bashrc` and there doesn't seem to be anything there to change my current directory, and there aren't any other relevant files in `/etc`.

What could be causing Cygwin's bash to change directory?

[image: ubuntu bash screenshot]

[image: cygwin bash screenshot]

Comment: Can you compare the output of running the bashes with `-x` added?

Comment: @choroba: I didn't know about that flag. The output is thousands of lines long, and completely different because I have different packages installed in Cygwin and Ubuntu (e.g. different versions of bash-completion). But notably, there's no `cd`, `cwd`, `pwd` or `pushd` in the output.

Comment: @choroba: I've found it thanks to you; I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you just add a command "cd /dir_you_want"  at the bottom of ～/.bashrc in cygwin

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that's exactly the opposite of what I want; I don't want to change directory when loading bash, I want to keep the directory bash was loaded in, so that I can use tools that open a bash terminal in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, so in case anyone runs into the same issue:

There's one file I neglected to look into, because I didn't know it exists, `/etc/profile`. In Cygwin, by default it has the following section in it:

```
# Make sure we start in home unless invoked by CHERE
if [ ! -z "${CHERE_INVOKING}" ]; then
  unset CHERE_INVOKING
else
  cd "${HOME}" || echo "WARNING: Failed attempt to cd into ${HOME}!"
fi
```

Disabling that solves the issue of course.